# VBA loop with array

Tags: vba, excel

I want to calculate number of rows conditionally,one condition for a pair of columns.   I wrote a Loop which operates for 3 columns now, (from j=3 to 5). I want to do the same Loop but for the sheet with 200 columns. If I will write like this "For j = 3 To 200 Step 3"  I will Count number of  all columns in the sheet, while i Need to Count and have result separately for every pair of columns. It seems I Need an Array, but I don't know how to write it.

```
Function RabigatorCount()
    Dim zelle As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Rabigator() As Integer
    Dim posMonitoring As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    Dim intCounter(3) As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer

    Set zelle = Cells.Find("is_monitoring_relevant")
    posMonitoring = zelle.Column

    For j = 3 To 5
        For i = 2 To 59

            If Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value = "c" And Cells(i, j + 1).Value < 0 And Cells(i, j + 2).Value < 0 Then
                intCounter(1) = intCounter(1) + 1
            ElseIf Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value = "c" And Cells(i, j + 1).Value = 0 And Cells(i, j + 2).Value < 0 Then
                intCounter(2) = intCounter(2) + 1
            ElseIf Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value = "c" And Cells(i, j + 1).Value > 0 And Cells(i, j + 2).Value > 0 Then
                intCounter(3) = intCounter(3) + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    RabigatorCount = intCounter

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of code certainly needs clarification.
May be it will help you:
*(however check it twice & thrice)*

```
Function RabigatorCount_Ori_15()
Dim zelle As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rabigator() As Integer
Dim posMonitoring As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim intLastRow As Integer
Dim intCounter(3) As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

    Set zelle = Cells.Find("is_monitoring_relevant")
    posMonitoring = zelle.Column

            Dim bPosMon As Boolean
            Dim lVal_1&, lSgnVal_1&
            Dim lVal_2&, lSgnVal_2&, bVal_2 As Boolean
            Dim lCntIdx&

    For j = 3 To 5
        For i = 2 To 59
            bPosMon = Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value = "c"
            Select Case bPosMon
                Case True
                    lVal_1 = Cells(i, j + 1).Value
                    lVal_2 = Cells(i, j + 2).Value

                    lSgnVal_1 = Sgn(lVal_1)

                    Select Case lSgnVal_1
                        Case 1
                            bVal_2 = (lVal_2 > 0)
                        Case Else ' 0, -1
                            bVal_2 = (lVal_2 < 0)
                    End Select

                    Select Case bVal_2
                        Case True
                            lCntIdx = lSgnVal_1 + 2
                            intCounter(lCntIdx) = intCounter(lCntIdx) + 1
                        Case False
                            ' do somthing else
                    End Select
                Case False
                    ' do somthing else
            End Select
        Next ' i
    Next ' j
    RabigatorCount = intCounter

End Function
```

.